# Hollow Inverted Half Pyramid

Tags: python

I have to print a hollow inverted pyramid:

```
******
*   *
*  *
* *
**
*
```

Following is my code:

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(n,0,-1):
    if i == n:
        print(n*'*', end = '')
    if  i > 1 and i <n:
        print('*'+(i-2)*' '+'*')
    else:
        print('*')
    print()
```

For input as 6 I am not sure why my code is printing 7 stars.
If anyone could help explain what I am doing wrong or missing would be really great!

Comment: `if  i > 1 and i <n:` ==> `elif  i > 1 and i <n:`.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit; each post should ask a single question.

Comment: Hint: instead of printing stars, try printing something totally different in each case. Then it should be clear, which of the `print`s are happening. When you try it that way, do you notice anything interesting? Please also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. There is no need for the `, end=''`. You still want a newline to print after this line of stars.
2. You used `if` not `elif` for the second condition, so the third block of code in the `else` will still run even if the first condition is true.

Here is the corrected code:

```py
n = int(input())

for i in range(n, 0, -1):
    if i == n:
        print(n * '*')
    elif 1 < i < n:
        print('*' + (i - 2) * ' ' + '*')
    else:
        print('*')
```

Comment: In this case you have to remove the `print()` at the end, otherwise not only do you need that `, end=''`, but you need it for the other two prints as well.

Comment: @DjaouadNM Didn't notice that `print()` at the end. It is fixed now

Answer (score 0):

If the first iteration of the loop, there are two `print` calls executing: the first one and the last, so that makes a total of 7 stars in that first line of output.

As the first and last case are different from the other cases, it is easier to just deal with those outside of the loop:

```
n = int(input())

print(n*'*')
for i in range(n - 3, -1, -1):
    print('*' + i*' ' + '*')
if n > 1:
    print('*')
```

There is still one `if` here to ensure it still works correctly for `n` equal to 1 or even 0.

To do it without that `if`, you could do this:

```
n = int(input())

print(n*'*')
s = '*' + n*' '
for i in range(n - 2, -1, -1):
    print(s[:i] + '*')
```

Comment: Thanks all, for the help. I ahave started learning python and yoiur answers really helped me understand the concepts

Answer (score -2):

another type of inverted hollow matrix:
54321
4  1
3 1
2 1
1

Answers:

## Hollow Right-angled triangle!!!

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(n,0,-1):
    for k in range(n,0,-1):
      if i==n or i==k or k==n-(n-1):
        print(k,end=" ")
    else:
        print(end="  ")
print()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [answer], and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. The answer section is for attempts to answer **the question, as asked**; please do not invent more features to implement. (Also, this code doesn't appear to do what you seem to claim it does, and it's hard to understand your explanation.)